# Sequence-based enumeration of permutations in lexicographic order

Tags: performance, comparative-review, swift, combinatorics

This is follow-up on
[On Knuth's "Algorithm L" to generate permutations in lexicographic order](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158798/on-knuths-algorithm-l-to-generate-permutations-in-lexicographic-order),
where I presented the following method to enumerate all permutations of array elements
in lexicographic order:

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable {

    /// Replaces the array by the next permutation of its elements in lexicographic
    /// order.
    ///
    /// It uses the "Algorithm L (Lexicographic permutation generation)" from
    ///    Donald E. Knuth, "GENERATING ALL PERMUTATIONS"
    ///    http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/fasc2b.ps.gz
    ///
    /// - Returns: `true` if there was a next permutation, and `false` otherwise
    ///   (i.e. if the array elements were in descending order).

    mutating func permute() -> Bool {

        // Nothing to do for empty or single-element arrays:
        if count <= 1 {
            return false
        }

        // L2: Find last j such that self[j] < self[j+1]. Terminate if no such j
        // exists.
        var j = count - 2
        while j >= 0 && self[j] >= self[j+1] {
            j -= 1
        }
        if j == -1 {
            return false
        }

        // L3: Find last l such that self[j] < self[l], then exchange elements j and l:
        var l = count - 1
        while self[j] >= self[l] {
            l -= 1
        }
        swap(&self[j], &self[l])

        // L4: Reverse elements j+1 ... count-1:
        var lo = j + 1
        var hi = count - 1
        while lo < hi {
            swap(&self[lo], &self[hi])
            lo += 1
            hi -= 1
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

*This* question is about using that method to create a Swift `Sequence` with all permutations, so that one can
simply enumerate these with `for .. in` loops and related techniques. My first approach is to use
the "type erasers" `AnySequence` and `AnyIterator`, which leads to this simple
implementation:

```
func permutations<T: Comparable>(of a: [T]) -> AnySequence<[T]> {
    var current = a.sorted()
    var done = false
    return AnySequence {
        return AnyIterator {
            if done { return nil }
            defer { done = !current.permute() }
            return current
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
for p in permutations(of: [3, 2, 1]) {
    print(p)
}

let allPerms = Array(permutations(of: ["B", "A", "C"]))
print(allPerms)
```

So this is easy to use, but what about performance? Here my benchmark code
(on a 1.2 GHz Intel Core m5 MacBook, compiled in Release mode):

```
let N = 10
var count = 0
let start = Date()
for _ in permutations(of: Array(1...N)) { count += 1 }
let end = Date()
print(count, end.timeIntervalSince(start))
```

This takes about **1.3 seconds,** i.e. it is much slower than calling `permute()` on a mutable
array in a loop, which takes only **0.03 seconds** (see [On Knuth's "Algorithm L" to generate permutations in lexicographic order](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158798/on-knuths-algorithm-l-to-generate-permutations-in-lexicographic-order)).

It gets a bit better if we implement our own sequence type instead of using the
type erasers:

```
struct PermutationSequence<T: Comparable>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    private var current: [T]
    private var done: Bool

    init(elements: [T]) {
        self.current = elements.sorted()
        self.done = false
    }

    func makeIterator() -> PermutationSequence {
        return self
    }

    mutating func next() -> [T]? {
        if done { return nil }
        let retval = current
        done = !current.permute()
        return retval
    }
}
```

Benchmark:

```
let N = 10
var count = 0
let start = Date()
for _ in PermutationSequence(elements: Array(1...N)) { count += 1 }
let end = Date()
print(count, end.timeIntervalSince(start))
```

which takes about **0.8 seconds.**

All feedback is welcome. In particular I am interested in making `Sequence`-based
enumeration of all permutations as fast as possible.

Comment: The implementation of `next()` in `PermutationSequence` will naturally induce, on each call, COW of `retval` when calling `permute` on `current`, but is it necessary to keep an extra copy of "next" state? (I.e., preparing `current` to be that copy for next `next()` call). As an alternative, we could let `next()` return `current`, and leave the choice of inducing COW to the caller, if necessary. E.g. implemented as avoiding permutation of `current` on first call to `next()`, and thereafter permuting and returning it (given `true`-return from `permute()`) for each subsequent call to `next()`.

Comment: ... _If_ using such an approach, another possible discussion point would be if there's a value in letting `permute()` return `Array?` rather than `Bool` (overhead only for COW on return?). On another note: interestingly, the 0.8s benchmark of the iteration over the `PermutationSequence` instance is comparable to the immutable implementation of `permute()` in the other thread, where, for the most part, the main difference is the extra copy on each call to `permute()`. Also, sorry for not benchmarking myself, but currently no where near my Mac, so can't test this compiled in release mode ><.

Comment: ... [a gist including the former and the latter](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/47a5ee4f393b5c55f3d9a0491f68f3e2).

Comment: Note that you don't need to include a `makeIterator()` implementation in your `PermutationSequence` that just returns `self`, as [there's already a default implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L631) for that :)

Comment: @Hamish: Indeed! (I originally had two separate types PermutationSequence and PermutationIterator, and then forgot about that when combining them to a single type).

Comment: @dfri: Indeed, the COWs decrease the performance. Returning `current.permute() ? current : nil` in the iterator (plus a check for the first iteration) brings it down to 0.12 seconds in my test (without changing the permute()  method).

Comment: Makes me wonder what is the cause for the remaining factor ~4 of worse performance of the sequence approach as compared to directly calling the mutating `permute()` in a while loop. W.r.t program flow, I believe the two scenarios should be very similar, but I guess that "unfolding" the (permutation) sequence comes with an overhead? (We've previously seen similar somewhat non-explainable overheads when comparing classic loops to the more Swifty ones, the prior approach seemingly always being the winner w.r.t. performance).

Comment: Well I've [found an implementation](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/5d463b997ba73a7a146d55def42d97f6) of `PermutationSequence` that has comparable performance to  repeatedly applying `permute()` directly :) Apparently having multiple points of exit from the method can prevent the compiler from performing *some* optimisation in order to make it as fast (you'll note in the gist if you uncomment the `return` in the `if` statement, the performance will drop to being ~4x worse).

Comment: I'm hoping to be able to reproduce this in a simpler example so I can examine the SIL emitted to figure out exactly *what* the optimisation is (the use of arrays usually bloats it beyond usefulness) – will look further into this tomorrow. (Not sure if this discovery on its own merits a partial answer.)

Comment: @Hamish nice job! Would be interesting to, parallelly, study if multi-exits can be a general performance issue (non-optimizations) or specific to more "heavy" use cases as this one (Array/`nil` multi-exit return) only. E.g., for the `permute()` implementation, I can't see that multi-exits for a boolean value should inhibit the optimizer, but you never know :)

Comment: @Hamish: According to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer, *"Every answer must make at least one insightful observation about the code in the question."* and your "discovery" certainly does that, so please do post an answer! – Btw, it seems that making `shouldContinue` a *constant* makes it a little bit faster.

Comment: @MartinR Okay, I'll go ahead and hopefully write up an answer later today :) Ah interesting w.r.t making `shouldContinue` a constant – I did actually try that, but couldn't notice a difference (although that being said, I was running other programs at the time, so the results I got were fluctuating a bit – I'll re-test).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Performance

I'm not particularly surprised that the version of `permutations(of:)` which uses `AnySequence` and `AnyIterator` is so slow.

You're paying for the cost of both:

- Heap allocation and reference counting for both the captured array and `done` flag.
- Copy-on-write upon mutating the array in the `defer` block, as a copy of the array needs to be taken in order to return it to the caller prior to the mutation.

Therefore immediately you can speed things up by simply reducing the amount of closure capture – for example if you just removed the `AnySequence` wrapper and just returned an `AnyIterator`:

```
func permutations<T: Comparable>(of a: [T]) -> AnyIterator<[T]> {
    var current = a.sorted()
    var done = false
    return AnyIterator {
        if done { return nil }
        defer { done = !current.permute() }
        return current
    }
}
```

You can still use an `AnyIterator` in a for-in loop due to the fact that it conforms to `Sequence` itself, and just returns itself as its own iterator. Iterating through it will 'consume' the elements returned, but you get the same behaviour by wrapping it in an `AnySequence` due to the fact that it's ultimately capturing the same array.

From `AnySequence` to `AnyIterator` improves my benchmark time (using the same measurement setup as shown in your question) from ~1.1 seconds to ~0.95 seconds.

However, as you note, we can do better than that by removing the closures *entirely* by simply declaring our own custom iterator type – `PermutationSequence`.

> ```
> struct PermutationSequence<T: Comparable>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
>     private var current: [T]
>     private var done: Bool
>
>     init(elements: [T]) {
>         self.current = elements.sorted()
>         self.done = false
>     }
>
>     func makeIterator() -> PermutationSequence {
>         return self
>     }
>
>     mutating func next() -> [T]? {
>         if done { return nil }
>         let retval = current
>         done = !current.permute()
>         return retval
>     }
> }
> ```

This reduces my benchmark time down to ~0.75 seconds.

However, the problem with this implementation, as [@dfri points out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158799/sequence-based-enumeration-of-permutations-in-lexicographic-order#comment301726_158799), is that we're *still* paying the cost of copy-on-write at each iteration due to the fact that both `retval` and `current` have a view onto the underlying array buffer.

The solution to this is fairly simple, [as you noted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158799/sequence-based-enumeration-of-permutations-in-lexicographic-order#comment301742_158799), we return the array after the mutation has taken place, and just maintain a flag so we don't do a mutation on the first iteration. This could look like:

```
struct PermutationSequence<Element : Comparable> : Sequence, IteratorProtocol {

    private var current: [Element]
    private var firstIteration = true

    init(startingFrom elements: [Element]) {
        self.current = elements
    }

    init<S : Sequence>(_ elements: S) where S.Iterator.Element == Element {
        self.current = elements.sorted()
    }

    mutating func next() -> [Element]? {

        // if it's the first iteration, we simply return the current array.
        if firstIteration {
            firstIteration = false
            return current
        }

        // do mutation – if the array has changed, then return it,
        // else we're at the end of the sequence.
        return current.permute() ? current : nil
    }
}
```

Note that I've also:

- Removed the `makeIterator()` implementation as [there's already a default implementation for this](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L631) when the sequence is its own iterator.
- Renamed the generic placeholder from `T` to `Element`, as it's a more descriptive name for it.
- Added an `init(startingFrom:)` initialiser, as I suspect it will be quite useful to allow the sequence to resume from a given permutation, rather than always starting at the first.
- Removed the argument label from `init(elements:)`, as it was already clear what the initialiser does and made it take a generic `Sequence` input for increased flexibility.

Now we're no longer paying for the cost of an array copy at each iteration due to the fact that the iterator always has a single view onto the array's buffer (though the `current` property), reducing my benchmark time down to ~0.1 seconds (the target is ~0.02 seconds for directly applying `permute()` in repeat-while loop).

The key to achieving the target performance weirdly *appears* to be avoiding having multiple exits in the implementation of `next()`.

If we refactor the iterator's `next()` method like this, so that there's only one `return`:

```
mutating func next() -> [Element]? {

    var continueIterating = true

    // if it's the first iteration, we avoid doing the permute() and reset the flag.
    if firstIteration {
        firstIteration = false
    } else {
        continueIterating = current.permute()
    }

    // if the array changed (and it isn't the first iteration), then return it,
    // else we're at the end of the sequence.
    return continueIterating ? current : nil
}
```

we are able to achieve the desired benchmark time of ~0.02 seconds. Exactly *why* this reduces the time so dramatically, I'm not too sure – it appears that having multiple points of exit in the method prevents the compiler from performing *some* important optimisation.

It also appears to be related to inlining, as when marking the `next()` method with the `@inline(never)` attribute, the use of an additional `return` has no significant impact on the performance. I'd certainly be interested if anyone else knows more about exactly what's going on here.

Regarding your comment about making `shouldContinue` (renamed to `continueIterating` here) a `let` constant – I could not observe a difference in performance in doing so, so I left it as a `var`.

#### Separating the sequence and iterator

Depending on your usage, it *may* be useful to separate your permutation sequence implementation from its iterator in order to allow for non-destructive iteration (this isn't required for a sequence, but can be useful in places).

This would just be as simple as having the sequence keep its own constant copy of the array prior to mutation, which gets passed to the iterator on its creation.

In Swift 3.1, this can be expressed rather nicely with a nested generic type:

```
struct PermutationSequence<Element : Comparable> : Sequence {

    // constant copy of the elements to pass to the iterator on its creation.
    let elements: [Element]

    init(startingFrom elements: [Element]) {
        self.elements = elements
    }

    init<S : Sequence>(_ elements: S) where S.Iterator.Element == Element {
        self.elements = elements.sorted()
    }

    struct Iterator : IteratorProtocol {

        private var current: [Element]
        private var firstIteration = true

        // you should create a PermutationSequence rather than invoking this
        // initialiser directly.
        fileprivate init(startingFrom elements: [Element]) {
            self.current = elements
        }

        mutating func next() -> [Element]? {

            var continueIterating = true

            // if it's the first iteration, we avoid doing the permute() and reset the flag
            if firstIteration {
                firstIteration = false
            } else {
                continueIterating = current.permute()
            }

            // if the array changed (and it isn't the first iteration), then return it,
            // else we're at the end of the sequence.
            return continueIterating ? current : nil
        }
    }

    func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
        return Iterator(startingFrom: elements)
    }
}
```

This shouldn't adversely affect the performance in any way (benchmarking doesn't reveal any significant difference) – an initial copy of the array may have to be taken upon the first mutation, but that's also true for the previous version of `PermutationSequence` due to the fact that the caller has a view onto the array buffer.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate  answer, providing lots of useful information! – Just one question: `Sequence` is not *required* to be non-destructive, correct?

Comment: @MartinR Happy to help! You are correct – a `Sequence` is not required to be non-destructive.