# Sequence-based enumeration of permutations with Heap's algorithm

Tags: performance, swift, combinatorics

[Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm)
is an algorithm to generate all permutations of a given array. It

> ... generates each permutation from the previous one by interchanging a single pair of elements; the other n−2 elements are not disturbed.

Here is my attempt to implement this algorithm in Swift 4 as a `Sequence`,
so that all permutations of an array can be enumerated with `for .. in`
loops and related techniques:

```
/*
 * A sequence of all permutations of a given array. Based on the
 * non-recursive version of Heap's algorithm as described in
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm
 */

struct HeapPermutationSequence<Element>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {

    private var current: [Element]
    private var c: [Int]
    private var i = 0
    private var firstIteration = true

    init(elements: [Element]) {
        self.current = elements
        self.c = Array(repeating: 0, count: elements.count)
    }

    mutating func next() -> [Element]? {
        if firstIteration {
            firstIteration = false
        } else {
            while i < c.count {
                if c[i] < i {
                    if i % 2 == 0 {
                        current.swapAt(0, i)
                    } else {
                        current.swapAt(c[i], i)
                    }
                    c[i] += 1
                    i = 0
                    break
                } else {
                    c[i] = 0
                    i += 1
                }
            }
        }
        return i < c.count ? current : nil
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
for p in HeapPermutationSequence(elements: [1, 2, 3]) {
    print(p, terminator: ", ")
}
print()

// Output:
// [1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2], [1, 3, 2], [2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1],
```

Several techniques from @Hamish's answer [Sequence-based enumeration of permutations in lexicographic order](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158799/sequence-based-enumeration-of-permutations-in-lexicographic-order/159375#159375) could be
applied here as well to improve the performance:

- Avoid the cost of copy-on-write by *not* mutating the `current` 
  array after it is returned as the next element.
- Have a single exit point in the `next()` method.

**Benchmark:**

```
let N = 10
var count = 0
let start = Date()
for _ in HeapPermutationSequence(elements: Array(1...N)) { count += 1 }
let end = Date()
print(count, end.timeIntervalSince(start))
```

which takes about 0.03 seconds (on a 1.2 GHz Intel Core m5 MacBook, compiled in Release mode).

All feedback is welcome, such as (but of course not restricted to):

- Performance improvements.
- Better variable names (`c` and `i` are simply copied from the Wikipedia
  pseudo-code).
- Simplifying the code, or making it better readable/understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been able to slash the execution time by almost half on my machine by declaring `current` and `c` as `ContiguousArray`:

```
struct HeapPermutationSequence<Element>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {

    private var current: ContiguousArray<Element>
    private var c: ContiguousArray<Int>
    private var i = 0
    private var firstIteration = true

    init(elements: [Element]) {
        self.current = ContiguousArray(elements)
        self.c = ContiguousArray<Int>(repeating: 0, count: elements.count)
    }

    mutating func next() -> ContiguousArray<Element>? {
        ...
    } 
}
```

### Benchmarks

Using the same benchmarking code, compiled with `-O` in the terminal, on a  2.7 GHz i7 MacBook Pro :

- Before: fluctuates between `0.126`s and `0.139`s
- After:  `0.07`s with inferior fluctuations, thanks to `current` being a `ContiguousArray`, since such a type has predictable performance.

---

I've got to `0.022`s by wrapping the benchmarking code in a `do` statement or any new scope (Makes the code 3x faster):

```
do {
    let N = 10
    var count = 0
    let start = mach_absolute_time()
    for _ in HeapPermutationSequence(elements: Array(1...N)) { count += 1 }
    let end = mach_absolute_time()
    print(count, Double(end - start)/Double(1e9))
}
```

Putting the original code inside a single iteration for loop `for _ in 0..<1 {...}` brings its execution time down to `0.020` too. Putting it inside a `do` statement, `repeat while false`, closure, `while true { ... break}`..., takes it back to `0.13`s .

**N.B:** The above result has only been observed on a mac (4 physical cores, 4 logical ones). On an iPhone and an iPad (both 2 physical cores), using a `ContiguousArray` makes the code a full second faster (`2.~`s vs `3.~`s).

---

We can gain `1` to `2ms` by rearranging the conditions:

```
private var notFirstIteration: Bool = false
//...
if notFirstIteration {
//...
} else {
    notFirstIteration = true
}
```

This would eliminate The `(N! - 1)` unnecessary *conditional jumps* in the assembly code.

---

As suggested by **Mr. Martin**: Not discarding manually the output of `HeapPermutationSequence` by using this code:

```
for x in HeapPermutationSequence(elements: Array(1...N)) { 
    count += x.count 
}
```

Gives a `+/-2ms` fluctuation in both solutions.

Comment: That is interesting. My original code, now compiled with Xcode 10.1, runs in approx.  0.16 seconds, that is much slower than what I measured when I wrote the question. With your modification, it reduces to 0.03 seconds.  Compiled with Xcode 9.2 both your and my code take about 0.025 seconds. Now the funny part: If I change the benchmark loop to `for x in HeapPermutationSequence(elements: Array(1...N)) { count += x.count }` (so that the return value is not ignored), then both your and my code run in 0.025 seconds, both with Xcode 9.2 and Xcode 10.1.

Comment: I have the feeling that for some reason, the performance of `Array` degraded in Xcode 10.1. According to the docs, Array and ContiguousArray should have similar efficiency if the element type is a struct.

Comment: @MartinR I am using Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2, and without ignoring the result (using x), with the original code, I get between `0.128`s and `0.132`s (no apparent improvement). With `ContiguousArray` I get between `0.072`s and `0.074`s. Ignoring the result gives me between `0.073`s and `0.075`s. So I do observe a slight improvement when the result is not discarded manually before entering the loop, and letting it be released automatically.

Comment: [This](https://forums.swift.org/t/performance-problems-with-swift-4-2/17663/4) explains why putting the code into a do-block (or for-loop) can affect the perfomance. It also seems that some performance differences depend on whether the compiler *inlines* the code or not. To get rid of these effects, I have put the HeapPermutationSequence code into a separate module, and now the results are 1.5 sec (my code) vs 0.5 sec (your code) on a 3.5 GHz Intel Core i5 iMac, and *independent* of whether the return value is ignored or not. – (Conclusion: benchmarking is difficult!)

Comment: (cont.) So ContiguousArray is indeed faster than Array, even for simple value types. It would be interesting to *why* that is, but that is a different question.

Comment: @MartinR With both codes in a new scope, your version is a `1ms` to `2ms` faster, and almost equal when rearranging the conditions (see the update). Mr. Ben Cohen has [pointed out](https://forums.swift.org/t/execution-time-contiguousarray-vs-array/12467/12) that it should be a bug in the optimizer. [`ContiguousArray`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/Arrays.rst#components) works here since the internal arrays don't get resized, no overhead of address offset calculations, and the fact that interoperability with obj-c is not a requirement here.

Answer (score 1):

`HeapPermutationSequence` computes all permutations of a given *array.* 
A common Swift idiom is not to operate on concrete types, but on *protocols.*
In this case, we need a mutable *collection* type which allows *efficient random access* to its elements. Therefore it makes sense to implement

```
struct HeapPermutationSequence<C>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol
    where C: RandomAccessCollection & MutableCollection
{
    init(elements: C) { ... }
    mutating func next() -> C? { ... }
}
```

instead, which is then applicable to more types. A simple example is
an *array slice:*

```
let slice = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].prefix(3)
for p in HeapPermutationSequence(elements: slice) {
    print(p)
}
```

There is not much that needs to be changed, only the index calculations 
become a bit verbose:

```
struct HeapPermutationSequence<C>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol
    where C: RandomAccessCollection & MutableCollection
{

    private var current: C
    private var c: [Int]
    private var i = 0
    private var firstIteration = true

    init(elements: C) {
        self.current = elements
        self.c = Array(repeating: 0, count: elements.count)
    }

    mutating func next() -> C? {
        if firstIteration {
            firstIteration = false
        } else {
            while i < c.count {
                if c[i] < i {
                    if i % 2 == 0 {
                        current.swapAt(current.startIndex,
                                       current.index(current.startIndex, offsetBy: i))
                    } else {
                        current.swapAt(current.index(current.startIndex, offsetBy: c[i]),
                                       current.index(current.startIndex, offsetBy: i))
                    }
                    c[i] += 1
                    i = 0
                    break
                } else {
                    c[i] = 0
                    i += 1
                }
            }
        }
        return i < c.count ? current : nil
    }
}
```

In my tests, the benchmark still runs in the same time with this implementation.